# SQL is group by all bad ? When yes how I rewrite my query?

Tags: sql

I have a product table and reviews table and want to show the products with the avg ratings

```
SELECT

p.*,
avg(r.rating) as avg_rating

FROM product p

LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.productId = p.id

GROUP BY p
```

I am new at SQL, so is the query bad ? And is group by all products also bad ? I have to group by all products because I want get all details to my frontend

Comment: If that's what gives you the desired result, go with it.

Comment: do you really need all the other columns from the products table? if you do, you will have to add all of them to the grouping.

Comment: usually you have different rows, so he average will be equal to the rating and so the query makes no sense

Comment: it doesn't make sense to select all columns with `p.*` and also aggregate the rating with `avg(r.rating)`. Should be something like `select p.product, avg(r.rating) as avg_rating....... group by p.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the database you are using, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL.

If you group by `p.id` instead of just `p` the query is perfectly valid. This is due to the functional dependency the rest of the columns of `product` have on the primary key.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN review r ON r.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Result:

```
 id  name     price  avg_rating             
 --- -------- ------ ---------------------- 
 2   Memorex  120    3.0000000000000000     
 3   Casio    105    1.00000000000000000000 
 1   TDK      100    null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eyRj8MtK).

Comment: But then I get this:  Expression `p` must depend only on group keys

Comment: That's not needed, if the database implements *functional dependency* properly. Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL? Type: `select version();` or `select @@version;` and post the result.